# WildFly 8.2, after every change in html file I need to perform full publish to see the changes, why?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, wildfly-8

After every change in HTML(XHTML) page of a web project, either it is **JSF** or a simple **WAR** I need to perform a **Full Publish** to see the changes. After some googling I found the solution to change in **Management Console** -  **Publishing settings** to **Automatically publishing when resources change** and set **publishing interval** to 0, but it doesns't help. What can I do more to resolve this issue? 
I'm using WildFly 8.2 on Mac Maverick. 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can deploy exploded war file instead of war archive. Only make sure that folder name has .war in its name e.g myApp.war.

After that you can configure wildfly deployment-scanner to auto deploy exploded content. This can be done in your config file e.g. standalone.xml.

See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Deployment+Scanner+configuration

Config example:

```
<deployment-scanner scan-interval="5000" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" path="deployments" auto-deploy-zipped="true" auto-deploy-exploded="true"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. In standalone.xml i added the attribute

```
auto-deploy-exploded="true"
```

and the problem started. After removing the attribute it returned to the same behaviour as before. 
There was a bug in JBoss 7 which was about processing this attribute not properly (or at all) but its status is resolved and it should work now. Obviously it doesn't or i am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

After setting auto-deploy-exploded="true" I was't able to deploy application. Deployment copies stuff in "deployment" and then scanner triggers and starts another deployment of the same app witch results in error